# Java Collections: Optimal way to update local database via a periodic job

Tags: java, collections, spring-data-jpa

I have a java based application that periodically fetches data from a web service and saves the data to a local database. The data from the local database is never deleted. When in a period, a particular record is not returned from the web service, then one of the flags for that record in the local database table is changed to indicate that it was not returned from the web service. So, the requirement is to update the local database with the changes received from the web services and update the flag for the records not returned.

I wrote the following code to update the status at object level(before persisting to the database), but I dont think this is optimal. Please advise on how this process can be optimized?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListUpdateTest
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<Person> local = new ArrayList<Person>(); // records in the local database

    local.add(new Person("firstName1", "lastName1", "email1", true));
    local.add(new Person("firstName2", "lastName2", "email2", true));
    local.add(new Person("firstName3", "lastName3", "email3", true));

    List<Person> remote = new ArrayList<Person>();// returned from the webservice

    remote.add(new Person("firstName1", "lastName1", "email1", true));

    update(local, remote);

}

private static void update(List<Person> local, List<Person> remote)
{
    for (Person localPerson : local)
    {
        if (!remote.contains(localPerson))
        {
            localPerson.setActiveFlag(false);
            // save the updated record to the database
        }
    }

    for (Person remotePerson : remote)
    {
        if (!local.contains(remotePerson))
        {
            // persist to database
        }
        else
        {
            // update local record
        }
    }
}
}


class Person
{
int     id;
String  firstName;
String  lastName;
String  email;
boolean activeFlag;

public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email, boolean activeFlag)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
    this.activeFlag = activeFlag;
}

public int getId()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName()
{
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName()
{
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName)
{
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail()
{
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email)
{
    this.email = email;
}

public boolean isActiveFlag()
{
    return activeFlag;
}

public void setActiveFlag(boolean activeFlag)
{
    this.activeFlag = activeFlag;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    if (obj == this)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null
        || obj.getClass() != this.getClass())
    {
        return false;
    }

    Person guest = (Person) obj;
    return id == guest.id
        && (firstName == guest.firstName || (firstName != null && firstName.equals(guest
            .getFirstName())))
        && (lastName == guest.lastName || (lastName != null && lastName.equals(guest
            .getLastName())));
}

@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime
        * result + ((firstName == null)
            ? 0 : firstName.hashCode());
    result = prime
        * result + id;
    result = prime
        * result + ((lastName == null)
            ? 0 : lastName.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Person [id="
        + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email
        + ", activeFlag=" + activeFlag + "]";
}
}
```

To accomplish these database operations, I am using Spring data jpa.

Comment: [JB Nizet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet): It does work.

Comment: No, it doesn't. contains() uses the equals() method, and you didn't override it. So it will only consider remote and local objects equal if they are the exact same object. In your example, for instance, the local collection does not contain the unique remote element, even though it contains a Person with the same firstName, lastName, email and activeFlag.

Comment: Edited the question with your inputs.

Comment: You should use HashSets instead of ArrayLists. `HashSet.contains()` is O(1). `ArrayList.contains()` is O(N). And you shouldn't have duplicates, and the order doesn't matter, so a Set is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the boolean to false on every Person record in the database before performing the update. Then all the updated Person records would get set back to true.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how useful is a boolean flag for your case. I would personally opt to a counter that is incremented each time a person is fetched (again). This would allow to get some useful (statistics) information instead of a boolean true/false (which is easy to mess up also).
Concerning optimization, don't use a for loop.
Use something like: `UPDATE table set flag=false WHERE id NOT IN(...)` passing the person ids fetched by the database. Not sure if you are using some sort of ORM and that is why you show code with objects in your OP